# Hiding all other members except for the single member group

Tags: multi-site-manager, ee1

We are working on multiple sites within an MSM installation and we need to create an administrative member group that has access to edit and approve members from only ONE single member group. We would like to hide all other members except for the single member group that they have administrative rights to.

Can we do this?

Comment: Back in the day we did this with the User module from Solspace. http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/  I don't think an EE1 version is available any longer.  If you don't want to build your own module you could probably get pretty close with just exp:query.

Comment: Thanks, but we aren’t worried about the front-end management, we are concerned with the backend of the MSM sites. Or, can we do exp:query for the backend???